# Is it permissible to plaster or build over graves to prevent someone from stealing the body?

Tags: grave

My dad passed away 4 months ago (killed by knife attack ) , some people are trying to dig the graveyard to steal bones (probably those who practice black magic).

I need to know how can I protect my father's  body from getting stolen by people?
How can we stop stealing dead body or bones from the graveyard if Islam does not allow us to any kind of constructions work as brickwork, plastering of the grave ..???

Comment: Waalaikumsalam, simply you can approach the authority that handle the graveyard to build fences around the whole area. However, this question is more likely to be an opinion based question and you should be dealing with the correct authority and law.

Comment: You do not have knowledge about what i was asking for and you came to give  answer here for nothing .. I do not need to ask the authority who build fences at graveyard .. because making fence is also prohibited in islam .